# Visual Studio 2005 always relinks the project when the project is generated with CMake

Tags: linker, cmake, visual-studio-2005

I have a project in Visual 2005 generated using CMake, and everytime I press F5 the linker relinks the objects, even if no modification was done. I have read other questions with similar problems, but the solution for them was:

1. The time of the windows was wrong. It was making the executable to be created with the time in the future. Or
2. The PDB created by the linker and by the compiler had the same name.

I've checked that and I don't have that problem. Also, I have another solution for the project (that was not generated by CMake) and it works fine. I've checked the properties of each project and they are similar.

This is the output generated in the BuildLog.htm:

> Build Log
>
> Build started: Project: remote4, Configuration: TTecDebug|Win32
>
> Command Lines
>
> Creating temporary file
>   "c:\advtec9\trunk\bin_sem_unittest\remote4\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\RSP00008649325832.rsp"
>   with contents [
>   /OUT:"c:\T\bin\smartclient\TTecDebug..\TSmartClient.exe" /VERSION:0.0
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt4\lib\TTecDebug" /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt4\lib"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\TTecDebug"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt4\plugins\imageformats"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt4\plugins\accessible\TTecDebug"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt4\plugins\accessible"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\kdchart4\lib\TTecDebug" /LIBPATH:"C:\kdchart4\lib"
>   /MANIFEST:NO /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEBUG
>   /PDB:"c:\T\bin\smartclient\TTecDebug/../TSmartClient.pdb"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
>   /IMPLIB:"c:\T\bin\smartclient\TTecDebug..\TSmartClient.lib" 
>   /machine:X86 /ignore:4217 /ignore:4049 /debug
>   /LIBPATH:C:/advtec9/trunk/openssl/debug kdchartd.lib qtmaind.lib
>   QtCored.lib QtGuid.lib Qt3Supportd.lib QtXmld.lib qtsvgd.lib
>   QtNetworkd.lib QAxServerd.lib QAxContainerd.lib qgifd.lib qjpegd.lib
>   qtaccessiblecompatwidgetsd.lib qtaccessiblewidgetsd.lib
>   C:/advtec9/trunk/senhap/splogin4d.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib
>   gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib
>   comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib  ssleay32.lib libeay32.lib mpr.lib imm32.lib
>   winmm.lib ws2_32.lib msimg32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
>   ..\lib_comm\TTecDebug\lib_comm.lib
>   ..\lib_getsys\TTecDebug\lib_getsys.lib
>   c:\T\bin\smartclient\TTecDebug..\singlesign.lib
>   ..\lib_graphicprint\TTecDebug\lib_graphicprint.lib
>   ..\lib\TTecDebug\lib.lib ..\lib_base\TTecDebug\lib_base.lib
>   ..\lib_gzip\TTecDebug\lib_gzip.lib ..\web\TTecDebug\web.lib
>   ..\third_libraries\engine_pkcs11\TTecDebug\engine_pkcs11.lib
>   ..\third_libraries\libp11\TTecDebug\libp11.lib dbghelp.lib
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\main.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\apcombase.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\apexcel.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\approject.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\apword.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\calc.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\calend4.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\config_client.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\execinclient.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\fjs_comps_base.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsaction.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsapplication.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsbitmap.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsdisplay.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsdisplayarray.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsexpandedinput.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsform.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jshelpwindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsinput.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsinputarray.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsinputcheck.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsinputfieldbmp.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsinputimage.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsinputradio.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsinputtext.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsmainwindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsmenu.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsmessagebox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jsmultilineinputtext.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jspromptinput.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jstoolbar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jswaitwindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\t4jswindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\qtcolortriangle.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\qtsingleapplication.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\remote_utils.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\rmtcli.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\signfunctions.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\talignlayout.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tapplication.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tbitmap.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tbrowsebutton.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tbtnbmp.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tbutton.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\crazychrs.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\parserext.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\Tprinter.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\Tprinterfonts.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\ttpviewer.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tcbrowse.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tchartwin.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tcheckbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tcombobox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tcomponentfactory.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tconnection.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tconnectionsocket.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tcontrol.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tcorretor.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tcreateinifiledialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgcanvas.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgcanvasitem.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgcanvasview.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgconnectorabs.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgconnectorline.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgconnectorpoly.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgdocument.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgeditor.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgrule.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgselectionbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgshape.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgshapeabs.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgshapebox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgshapeicon.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgundolog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdgviewer.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tdialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\teventbuffer.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tfileman.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tfolder.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tget.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tgetdados.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tgraphicprint_client.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tgroupbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tguicommand.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\thelpbaloon.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\thelpdialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\thotkeys.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tibrowser.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tinifile_client.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tlibmanager.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tlistbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tlocallog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmenu.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmenubar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmenupopup.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmessage.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmessagebar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmessagebox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmessagehook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmeter.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmodaldialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmscalendar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmscalendgrid.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmsgrun.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmsselbr.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tmultiget.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tnanfor.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tobjecthook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tolecontainer.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tpageview.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tpanel.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tparametersform.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tprinterhook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tprinterspool.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tradiobutton.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\trashook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tremoteopensave.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\treportprinter.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tresourcemanager.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tsay.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tsbutton.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tscrollbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tsplash.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\ttab.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tterminal.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tterminalupd.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\ttimer.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\ttoolbar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\ttree.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tvalue.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tverticalscrollbar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\twindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tworkspace.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tworkspacefolder.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tworktime.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\waitrun.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tgrid.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\httpclient.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\tpaintpanel.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\ttimerhook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\qtsingleapplication_win.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\rational_robot.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\remote41.res"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\qrc_remote4.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_calc.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_calend4.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsaction.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsapplication.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsdisplayarray.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsexpandedinput.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsform.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jshelpwindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsinput.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsinputarray.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsinputcheck.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsinputfieldbmp.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsinputimage.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsinputradio.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsinputtext.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsmainwindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsmenu.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsmessagebox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jsmultilineinputtext.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jspromptinput.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jstoolbar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_t4jswindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_qtcolortriangle.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_qtsingleapplication.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_talignlayout.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tapplication.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tbitmap.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tbtnbmp.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tbutton.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_Tprinter.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tcbrowse.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tchartwin.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tcheckbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tcombobox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tcontrol.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tcorretor.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tcreateinifiledialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgcanvasview.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgconnectorline.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgdocument.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgeditor.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgrule.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgshape.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgshapebox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgshapeicon.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdgviewer.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tdialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tfolder.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tget.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tgetdados.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tguicommand.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_thelpbaloon.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_thelpdialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tlistbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmenu.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmenupopup.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmessagebar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmessagebox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmodaldialog.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmscalendar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmscalendgrid.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmsselbr.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tmultiget.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tobjecthook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tolecontainer.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tpageview.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tpanel.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tparametersform.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tprinterhook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tprinterspool.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tradiobutton.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tremoteopensave.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_treportprinter.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tresourcemanager.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tsay.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tscrollbox.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_ttab.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tterminal.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_ttoolbar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_ttree.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tverticalscrollbar.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_twindow.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tworkspace.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tworkspacefolder.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tworktime.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tgrid.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_httpclient.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_tpaintpanel.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_ttimerhook.obj"
>
> ".\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\moc_splogin.obj" ] Creating command line
>   "link.exe
>   @c:\advtec9\trunk\bin_sem_unittest\remote4\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\RSP00008649325832.rsp
>   /NOLOGO /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"
>
> Output Window
>
> Linking...
>
> Results
>
> Build log was saved at
>   "file://c:\advtec9\trunk\bin_sem_unittest\remote4\remote4.dir\TTecDebug\BuildLog.htm"
>   remote4 - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've (finally!) found out what my problem was.

I have a project with some sub-directories. In the CMakeLists.txt of each subdirectory, I was defining a project name (with the command `project()` ). This was causing visual studio to behave like that.

When I removed the `project()` of the sub_directories the problem was solved.